# uicollectionview - data automatically load without calling reloaddata

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, reloaddata

I got two questions.

1. I am wondering why my collection view automatically load data without calling `imageCollectionView.reloadData()`.

   Solved. See comment
2. Why `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize` is not called? I didn't see the `print("collectionViewLayout called")` I am trying to modify the cell's size so the cell's height equals to the collection view height

   Solved. See comment

Here is the codes

```
class ProductInternalDetailVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    var selectedProduct: Product?
    @IBOutlet weak var imageCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imageCollectionView.delegate = self
        imageCollectionView.dataSource = self
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! ProductInternalDetailCVC
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell.productImage.image = selectedProduct!.image1
        } else {
            cell.productImage.image = selectedProduct!.image2
        }
        cell.productImage.frame = CGRect(x: 1, y: 1, width: cell.frame.size.width-2, height: cell.frame.size.height-2)
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        //return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.height-1, height: collectionView.frame.size.height-1)
        print("collectionViewLayout called")
        return CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
    }
}

class ProductInternalDetailCVC: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var productImage: UIImageView!
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize ` is different from the one in the doc: `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize` (It's missing a `_` like the other ones.

Comment: CollectionView automatically loads for the first time, after `viewDidLoad`, I hope you know that :)

Comment: Oh Thanks guy. All question solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Question 2: The function signature has changed a bit. Change the function signature with this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    ... 
}
```

And don't forget to implement the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol.

Question 1:

When entering the ViewController your collectionView loads the datasource of the collectionView automatically if this is your question.for example, make changes on datasource without changing the view (means without calling `viewDidLoad` method) you will not see the changes until you call `imageCollectionView.reloadData()`.

Comment: HI, @kingalione will you please help me out, i have same issue and  i am stuck in this situation.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I have folders cells on top and other data cells displayed on the collection view , on click of folder it is opening same collectionviewcontroller but other instance so when i click back so on previous view controller i have not called reload data still it is triggering all the collection view methods @Kingalione If you have any idea let me know what I am doing wrong